# C# should Singleton contain static methods?

Tags: c#, methods, static, singleton, non-static

I am having a lot of trouble choosing between using `Singleton` or `Static` for a class that contains state variables. I wanted the class object to instantiate and exist only as one.

I know both ways can store state variables. `Static` Class seems easy to deal with the variables as all methods will become `static`, which they can access the `static` variables without any further work.

However, this case is different for a `Singleton`. I have both kinds of methods; A kind that needs to access to the `Singleton`'s `Instance` variable, and other that without any access to the `Instance` variable, which I can mark it static.

An Example:

```
/// <summary>Singleton.</summary>
    public sealed class Singleton
    {
        private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton(); /// <summary>Instance.</summary>
        public static Singleton Instance { get { return instance; } }

        private int integer; /// <summary>Integer.</summary>
        public int Integer { set { integer = value; } get { return integer; } }

        /// <summary>Constructor.</summary>
        private Singleton() { }

        /// <summary>TestA</summary>
        public void TestA(int val)
        {
            Integer = val;
        }

        /// <summary>TestB</summary>
        public static int TestB(int val)
        {
            return Instance.Integer * val;
        }

        /// <summary>TestC</summary>
        public static int TestC(int val)
        {
            return val * val;
        }
    }
```

From the example given above, there are three methods; `TestA`, `TestB`, and `TestC`.

1. `TestA` is a `non-static` instance method that has access to its property.
2. `TestB` is a `static` method, but accesses the `Instance` to get its properties.
3. `TestC` is a `static` method that the instance has no use.

This begs the question:

1. Should the `Singleton` contains only `static` methods, and access to its `Instance` properties and methods by going through the `static` `Instance` property? In other words, all methods are similar to `TestB` or `TestC`.
2. Should the `Singleton` contains only `non-static` methods, regardless whether if it needs the `Instance` or not? All methods similar to `TestA`.
3. Should the `Singleton` contains both mixed `static` and `non-static` (in this case, `TestA`, and `TestB` kind) methods? Which I believe it can get rather messy.
4. If not, what should I do? Should I dump the idea of `Singleton`, and go with all `static` for every classes that is to be instantiated only once?

Edit: With similar question, should `Singleton` even contain any `Static` variables/field/properties beside the `Instance`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldnt mix up both patterns.

If you have an Singleton pattern the only static field should be the Instance(+ the getter). All your methods and fields should be accessible through the instance. If you mix it up it will only cause confusion.

If you choose the the static class pattern don't use a secret instance inside thats the job of .NET.

If you are not sure what pattern fits best for you, have a look into this Singleton-vs-Static article. It explains the pro's and con's of both of them: https://www.dotnetperls.com/singleton-static